# NullReferenceException in Rossharp PoseStampedPublisher

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ros

I am using rossharp to connect ROS to Unity application that I build in IOS. However, in application, it doesn't work and gives following error,

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.   at
>   RosSharp.RosBridgeClient.PoseStampedPublisher.UpdateMessage ()
>   [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0    (Filename:
>   currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

Comment: Is the published running on your ROS machine? When you run your Unity App, can you confirm that App successfully connected to RosBridge server?

Comment: No it is not running on ROS machine. I am sure that the unity app is connecting to ROS machine. 
The rossharp package , posestamped publisher.cs file is working successfully between ros machine and unity on mac computer. However when i connect ros machine to unity app i see the null exception error on xcode. When building in ios the error is occured.
Is there a problem with link.xml or player settings or should i change my code in pose stamped publisher.cs